# shared htaccess: redirect multiple domain roots

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My situtation is that multiple domains share a htaccess file and I need to redirect the root / to each language folder.

So I want ONLY the root / of each domain to be redirected like:
www.my-en.com/ to redirect to /en/
and
www.my-de.de/ to redirect to /de/

Unfortunately I need to accomplish this with htaccess as I CANNOT change any other settings. 
So far all solutions I found look like this
redirct 301 /old-path http://www.new-domain.com
which will always be applied to all domains using the htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-en\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.my-en.com/en/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-de\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.my-de.de/de/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect others to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Works absoluetly perfect! thanks! Would you also happen to know how I could force each Domain to only use www?

Comment: I add now the www redirect

Comment: Great. Excactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Why did you remove NE now? Ahh you moved it down after the other rules...I see

Comment: Yes, to avoid 2 redirect for root without www

Comment: Strangely for my-en.com I DO get 2 redirects. With my-de.de it is only ONE.

Comment: That can be a problem if you have not cleared the cache, or incorrectly corrected a domain name from my template

Comment: I checked with an external tool https://httpstatus.io/ could it still be my cache?

Comment: Others rules in htaccess ?